# Detecting the tenant without any user interaction

Tags: http, multi-tenant

I am developing a multi tenant CMS, where the specific clients domain urls are redirected to my multi tenant application url (e.g. client-a.com is redirected to my-multi-tenant-application.com). Each client have spesific content and design elements, assembled into a common html/css frame.

When a user logs in, I know which tenant they represent by storing user-tenant relations internally. But the problem is; how do I detect which url was originally requested, so that I can display the correct content before the user has actually logged in, or to a visitor that has no credentials at all?

I would assume this is a quite common situation, but can not find a good solution. I don't want to use the *referer* HTTP-header.